# Is there a way to check (forever) if the length of a certain string is divisible by a certain number?

Tags: python

In the code that I am trying to make here, I need it to continually check whether the length of the string is divisible by 3, output a valid output if it is, and looping again if it does not. I have defined all other variables in my code beforehand, e.g. a, u().

```
def u():
  if int(len(str(a))) ('is divisible by 3'):
    print('The sum of all characters in that string is divisible by 3')
  while int(len(str(a)))  ('is not divisible by 3'):
    print('The sum of all characters in that string is NOT divisible by 3, try again!')
    u()
u()
```

A short and effective answer would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you show an example that explains what you want?

Comment: You might want to pass the string `a` to your function.  Once you do that you can either write a `while` loop repeatedly calling the function or put the iteration inside the function - whatever works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I used  take input from user and check if satisfies condition or not.

```
def u():

  a = input(' Input string ')
  if int(len(str(a)))%3 ==0:   #('is divisible by 3'):
      print('The sum of all characters in that string is divisible by 3')
  else: # int(len(str(a)))  ('is not divisible by 3'):
      print('The sum of all characters in that string is NOT divisible by 3, try again!')
      u()
u()
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps so much! I appreciate your time!